# How operating system store file that was edited by user?

Tags: file, io, operating-system, filesystems

I know that file system use clusters (n x sectors (512 B) usualy 4KB in size) for storing files. If I have file of size 5 KB then it use two cluster to store and remaining space is called slack space. My question is related to situation where user read file from disk, modify (add few characters) and save this file again. What will happened, will OS (overwrite) write file from location from it started to read file, or file will be writen in new cluster completely, and address of file starting cluster will be erased and replaced with new cluster address.

new part:

I just read in a book "Information technologie:An Introduction for Today’s Digital World" that if file use 2 bloks (clusters) and second file use 4 consecutive blocks after first file. First file is edited and modified, his file size increased to total of 3 blocks. This file will be writen after second file and previously occupied 2 blocks are free. But still don t know what will happend if I for example increase file with one character and file is still smaller then total of 2 blocks. Will this data be added on existing file, to existing first two blocks, or it will be stored on new disk physical location (new 2 blocks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user store file it will occupy some space on disk (cluster = combine several sectors = 4 KB since sector is usually 512 bytes). If file take 3KB then 1KB stay unused in this cluster. Now what will happened if I increase little file adding some data to this file. Answer now depend of procedure that user use to modify file.
 
1. If I manualy add data to file (using echo "some text" >> filename) this data will add this data in existing cluster since there is 1KB of space availabile. If file site increase it will take another free sectors (file use "extents" to address all this sectors)
2. If i use text editor it will copy file on other location on disc (because of multiuser and situation when two users access same file in a same time). Previous location will be "free" (content in sector stay but File system don t have reference to that) and replace with new location on disk.

Since majority of users use some editor for editing file then scenario 2 is most common.